# Cannot set 1080p resolution in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, resolution

I am working on Ubuntu 10.04. I bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu 10.04 on it.

However, I tried a lot of methods found from the internet such as using xrandr, modifying the xorg.conf to increase the resolution, it eventually fail and only 800x600 is working.

I want it become 1920x1080.

What should I do?

Thank you.

This is what I get from lspci -vnn:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0100] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f8000000-fb0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000bfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at fb307000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1a.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05) (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fb306000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8444]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at fb300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fb200000-fb2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: fb100000-fb1fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05) (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fb305000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1c5c] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 4 port SATA IDE Controller [8086:1c00] (rev 05) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at fb304000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 2 port SATA IDE Controller [8086:1c08] (rev 05) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:844d]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f030 [size=16]
    I/O ports at f020 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] [10de:0622] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:070e]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
    Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fb000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia-173, nvidiafb, nouveau

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8432]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at c0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

05:00.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Device [1b21:1042] (prog-if 30)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8488]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fb200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci

07:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Device [1b21:0612] (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:84b7]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    I/O ports at c050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c030 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c020 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=32]
    Memory at fb100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Comment: 1) This is pretty vague as far as these types of questions go. Your video card, at a minimum, is really important to know when dealing with issues like this. Seeing your `xorg.conf` would also probably help. 2) This is pretty clearly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @elderathsis, modern Ubuntu installs don't generally create a xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx does not have driver support for the Intel Sandy Bridge platform, as it was released almost a full year after Lucid was.

Consider upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal or any distribution that ships a Linux kernel with version 2.6.38 or later, as full Sandy Bridge support was added in these versions.

The [Ubuntu Kernel Team offers newer versions of the Linux kernel for Lucid in their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa), but their website warns you, "Don't come crying to the kernel team if it kills all of your kittens."  In combination with the [latest X Intel drivers](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates), that should get you Sandy Bridge support on Lucid.  To install it, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repostiory ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get install linux-lts-backport-oneric
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I tried it but failed.

Comment: It said screen cannot be larger than 800x600 (desired size 1920x1080)

Comment: and now it don't know why said: can't open display

Comment: @user: Hmm, might be a driver issue.  Please edit your answer and provide the output of `lspci -vnn`

Comment: it works once. My monitor name (corresponding to "LVDS1") is "DVI-I-2"
when I have done the above, it works! But when I restart the computer.
It change to 640x800 which is even lower than the resolution the OS just installed, and the monitor name become "default".

I tried to repeat the step but it failed:

Configure crtc 0 failed

Comment: Sorry. I got the reason now. It is because I installed the driver of NVIDIA

Comment: @user: I updated my answer based on your `lspci` output.

Comment: I really thank you so much for your help....!!!! You are really an angel to me. In fact, I have been working on the installation of ubuntu 11.04, but I cannot find the reason why it is not able to be installed.... I tried a lot of methods such as using different dvd and different version 32 or 64 bit of ubuntu and using USB (using universal installer and Yumi), but it eventually failed....

I also posted a question about it:
http://superuser.com/questions/324921/cant-install-ubuntu-64-bit-on-my-asus-destop