# Can't install Ubuntu 64 bit on my Asus Destop

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-11.04

I want to start installing Ubuntu on my new computer with an Asus P8H61-M Pro motherboard. The CPU is an i5 2400 3.1GHz, it has 8GB of RAM.

I tried to burn the `amd64.iso` to different DVDs and then install, it eventually failed.

Could it be that my machine/hardware does not support 64bit Ubuntu? What can I do?

---

**Clarification:**

I burned the image to the disk, not just put it in the disk.... It failed when it loaded the disk, it stop at the black screen stage with a static white underline on the left top corner.....or it stop at the ubuntu page which show the logo ubuntu under which, few dots are changing color but it stop changing color and the whole process stoped forever.....eventually.

Adds:

I have a DDR3 display installed on the mother board as well. Will it be a reason that the ubuntu cannot install?

I have tried 32bit and 64 bit. ..both failed...

I also tried to use the same disk in my old notebok, it works!!

So, will it be a problem of hardware so that I cannot install ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: "It eventually failed". What failed *exactly*?

Comment: How did you burn the image? you need to burn the image to the disk, not put the image as file on the disk.

Comment: All i5 support 64 bit.

Comment: I burned the image to the disk, not just put it in the disk....
It failed when it loaded the disk, it stop at the black screen stage with a static white underline on the left top corner.....or it stop at the ubuntu page which show the logo ubuntu under which, few dots are changing color but it stop changing color and the whole process stoped forever.....eventually.

Comment: Are you sure you burned it correctly? Else, if you have an USB stick you can put it on there (Google for Linux USB Boot) and you'll be set.

Comment: I have tried to use USB as well.
It failed again and again. It stop at a stage which showed me a black back and white words with some error:
ata6.00: failed command: IDENTITY PACKET DEVICE
ata6.00: cmd at/00.......
ata6.00: res 40/00 .........
ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
ata6: hard resetting link

It stoped eventually at ata6: hard resetting link......

Comment: Have you been able to run any other operating system on the machine? If you haven't then there might be some hardware issue. You might want to try using something like Yumi to create a live USB stick with Ubuntu on it. This greatly simplifies the process of creating a bootable USB stick.

Comment: I have tried to install ubuntu 10.04 32bit it works....
but I tried to install ubuntu 11.04 both 32 and 64 bit....it failed

Comment: What is "a DDR3 display installed on the mother board"? Are you using a 3rd party video card instead of the onboard graphics ports? Maybe you can paste a link to some product information?

Comment: yes. That is a 3rd party display card but not the on board one

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, trying with USB instalation (11.10, 64bit)...
I cannot install ubuntu, and also many times the bios menu is crashing..
I restart many times until something will work. Did u solve this finally?
Thanx

Comment: I still cannot solve it. It succeed to install 10.04, but failed for 11 and 12